# How to call an Activity from Render Method in libGDX for Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a simple game in Android using libGDX. Its just a catching game in which there are some items which will be falling from top of the screen, also there is a basket at the bottom and user will scroll the basket to collect those items.After some seconds the game will get finished, now in Render method I have a condition on which I need to over the game say after 30 seconds. So I have to call an activity in which I need to display GAME OVER image but I am not able to figure out how can I call this activity from Render method.

I am new to libGDX, and I dont know how to do this. Can anyone help me to sort out this. Any help would be appreciable. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you "call" another activity? You can handle this inside your activity, e.g. by using different `Screen`s.

Comment: actually I don't know much about this Frame Work. Can you help me with that?

Comment: libGDX is huge. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki should help you with nearly all basic problems though.

Comment: I have created another screen and in Render method I m starting that class accordingly but nothing is happening. How should I hide the current activity and start another. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for displaying the image you should try using a stage will make your life much easier. In the stage you can add as many widgets (Actors) you want and then by just calling stage.draw() they will be rendered for you. Check below how this could be done.

```
public class GameOver implements com.badlogic.gdx.Screen{

  final Drop game;
  Image gameOverImage;
  Stage gameOverStage; // add this
  TextureRegion textureRegion; // Get region from texture
  TextureRegionDrawable textureRegionDrawable; // drawable from textureRegion

// O̶r̶t̶h̶o̶g̶r̶a̶p̶h̶i̶c̶C̶a̶m̶e̶r̶a̶ ̶c̶a̶m̶e̶r̶a̶; // No need of this stage's viewport has camera

public GameOver(final Drop gam) {

    Log.d("Called ","Called ");

    game = gam;

    gameOverStage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(yourDesiredwidth, yourDesiredHeight)); 
     // You can use different Viewport class if you want see Viewport in Documentation

    textureRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("game_over.png"));
    textureRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(textureRegion);
    gameOverImage = new Image(textureRegionDrawable );
    gameOverImage.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

    stage.add(gameOverImage);
   //c̶a̶m̶e̶r̶a̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶O̶r̶t̶h̶o̶g̶r̶a̶p̶h̶i̶c̶C̶a̶m̶e̶r̶a̶(̶)̶; // No need of this see above
  // c̶a̶m̶e̶r̶a̶.̶s̶e̶t̶T̶o̶O̶r̶t̶h̶o̶(̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶,̶ ̶8̶0̶0̶,̶ ̶4̶8̶0̶)̶; // Same

}
```

and in the render method call stage.draw() so all the actors of the stage get rendered including your image:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(); // If you want the actors in stage to move or do some other work
    stage.draw(); // Draws all the actors

/* Below is for painting your text although it could be done by creating a Label Actor and add it in stage as the image*/
    stage.getBatch().begin();
    game.font.setColor(0,0,0,1);
    game.font.setScale(3);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Game Ends!!! ", 100, 150);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Tap To restart", 100, 100);
    stage.getBatch().end();

}
```

Second for showing a Game Over window you can create a Table, add all your game over actors in the table and then when you want to show it you just add the table to the stage. You can read more about Table in the documentation It's a bit tricky at the beginning but you will ge the rewards later.

Comment: it will automatically hide the previous screen from which I am calling this Screen ??

Comment: For Game Over window I would make a table, then add A label and 2-3 buttons in the table. To show the table you add it to the stage like: stage.add(table);. And then you can remove it when you don't want it to be shown. And yes it will be rendered above your screen.

Comment: Also the     gameOverImage = new Image(textureRegionDrawable); line is giving error, what should I import for the Image class ?

Comment: What do you mean? Find the imports from the documentation if you are not using an IDE to help you. Start with this for the Image class http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html

Comment: Khan you can also do this if it's more convienient to you:          `new Image (new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("game_over.png"));`             The only drawback is that only when using a TextureRegionDrawable will the actor's scale, rotation, and origin be used when drawing.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a job for another Activity. Instead, one option is to use diffrent Screens from within your main Activity. More info here: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses

Alternatively, you could simply keep track of your game's state (plaing, paused, game over, etc) and draw different things depending on that state. Something like this:

```
public void draw(){
   if(state == playing){
       //draw game
   }
   else if(state == gameOver){
      //draw game over
   }
}
```

Comment: I have created another screen and in Render method I m starting that class accordingly but nothing is happening.
How should I hide the current activity and start another. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @SalmanKhan Why don't you read what we are telling you? You should NOT start another activity.

Comment: @noone, I have created screen not the activity sorry for mistyping.

Comment: @noone, now in my next screen I wanna show an image but if I am rendering the Image its not going to next screen, but if I am rendering only text its working fine. Can you help me to sort this out ?

Comment: Hey @noone, I have posted the source code for the new screen. Please check it.